# Trying to remove child with mouseclick

Tags: actionscript-3, removechild, addchild, displayobject

So, my question is as follows.

Why am I getting this error

(TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter child must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/removeChild()
    at TargetMain/killTarget())

when trying to remove objects from the stage with a mouse click?

My code for the application is below.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.text.*;
    import flash.ui.Keyboard;

    public class TargetMain extends MovieClip
    {
        public function TargetMain()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, spawner);//Spawning function listener

            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, killTarget);//Clicking function listener
        }

        public function spawner(k:KeyboardEvent):void
        {
            if(k.keyCode == 32)
            {
                trace ("spawned");
                var theTarget:ParaspriteFull = new ParaspriteFull();

                theTarget.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * stage.stageWidth);
                theTarget.y = Math.floor(Math.random() * stage.stageHeight);
                addChild(theTarget);

            }
        }

        public function killTarget(toDie:MouseEvent):void
        {
            trace ("clicked")
            var deadTarget:ParaspriteFull = (toDie.target as ParaspriteFull);
            //Below is where I continually get an error and do not know how to fix it.
            //This is also after searching the internet for hours trying to solve my issue.

            //MovieClip(deadTarget).parent.removeChild(deadTarget);
            removeChild(deadTarget);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error means deadTarget is null, so if you just want to remove deadTarget from stage, try this

```
 var deadTarget:DisplayObject = toDie.target as DisplayObject;

 if ( deadTarget && deadTarget.parent) {
     deadTarget.parent.removeChild(deadTarget);
 }
```

Or you should find out the actural type of deadTarget.

Answer (score 0):

You are listening for click on stage. So, any clicks (whether it's on ParaspriteFull object or not) would fire `killTarget`. One way to avoid exception is to do as Pan has suggested in the answer to essentially do nothing in click `killTarget` if the clicked object isn't of type ParaspriteFull.
But, I'd suggest to listen for clicks on ParaspriteFull objects and not on stage. i.e. remove

```
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, killTarget);//Clicking function listener
```

from your `constructor` and modify `spawner` function to add click listener as:

```
theTarget.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, killTarget);//Clicking function listener
```

Also, remove listener on ParaspriteFull object in `killTarget` as:

```
deadTarget.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, killTarget);//Remove clicking function listener
```